# Tor hidden service file permission problem

Tags: tor

I have installed Tor on Ubuntu 14.04 according to instructions at https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

I got the basic relay configured and working but I have file permission issues with file permissions of a hidden service private_key and hostname files. Tor is started as root, it will do some magic and then it drops itself to run as "debian-tor".

File permissions:

```
sudo ls -l /home/debian-tor /home/debian-tor/tor_keys =>
/home/debian-tor:
total 4
drwx------ 2 debian-tor debian-tor 4096 Jul 17 10:59 tor_keys

/home/debian-tor/tor_keys:
total 8
-rw------- 1 debian-tor debian-tor  23 Jul 17 10:59 hostname
-rw------- 1 debian-tor debian-tor 891 Jul 16 17:52 private_key
```

Starting as a service (does not work):

```
sudo service tor start =>
[notice] Tor 0.2.6.10 (git-71459b2fe953a1c0) opening new log file.
[warn] Could not open "/home/debian-tor/tor_keys/private_key": Permission denied
[warn] Error reading private key from "/home/debian-tor/tor_keys/private_key"
[err] Error loading private key.
[warn] Error loading rendezvous service keys
[err] set_options(): Bug: Acting on config options left us in a broken state. Dying.
```

Starting from command line (works!):

```
sudo tor =>
[notice] Tor 0.2.6.10 (git-71459b2fe953a1c0) opening log file.
[notice] Tor v0.2.6.10 (git-71459b2fe953a1c0) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1f and Zlib 1.2.8.
[notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
[notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
[notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9052
[notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
[notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
[notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
...
[notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

Test to have an other user own the files (this shows that tor is really running as debian-tor):

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu_user:ubuntu_user /home/debian-tor
sudo service tor start =>
 * Checking if tor configuration is valid
Jul 17 12:23:06.811 [notice] Tor v0.2.6.10 (git-71459b2fe953a1c0) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1f and Zlib 1.2.8.
Jul 17 12:23:06.811 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jul 17 12:23:06.811 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Jul 17 12:23:06.811 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jul 17 12:23:06.814 [warn] /home/debian-tor/tor_keys is not owned by this user (debian-tor, 108) but by ubuntu_user (1000). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Jul 17 12:23:06.814 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
Jul 17 12:23:06.814 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Trying to get Tor re-create keys:

```
sudo rm -r /home/debian-tor/tor_keys
sudo service tor start =>
[notice] Tor 0.2.6.10 (git-71459b2fe953a1c0) opening log file.
[warn] Error creating directory /home/debian-tor/tor_keys: Permission denied
[warn] Error loading rendezvous service keys
[err] set_options(): Bug: Acting on config options left us in a broken state. Dying.
```

Running `sudo tor` would create the folder and write hostname and private_key files there.

So my question is how could I get `sudo service tor start` working? It somehow does not have root nor debian-tor privileges to write there, or maybe I am missing something. Or should I just not use the `/etc/init.d/tor` script to manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple answer - AppArmor. It limits resources for you services. You can find details here `man apparmor` or look here http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/QuickProfileLanguage

So you have to add rules to /etc/apparmor.d/local/system_tor

```
# Site-specific additions and overrides for system_tor.
# For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.

/home/debian-tor/tor_keys/* rwmk,
```

Then `sudo service apparmor restart`
And it will work like a sharm.

`sudo service tor restart`

`sudo service tor status`

`tail /var/log/tor/log`

`torify links my_abracadabra.onion`

and so on...